# Usage of "as a ___,"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I read a statement similar to this: "As a research-intensive lab, interns are required..." I thought that the noun that follows the comma is to be modified by the object of 'as', which isn't the case in the example. Is the example or my thinking correct?

Comment: You are correct, that pattern is being used incorrectly.

Comment: //As a research-intensive lab, interns are required..."// It sounds like 'interns are the labs.'

Comment: To be merciful, we could say that the reader fills in the missing connection to absorb the correct intent.

Comment: I'm duplicating another comment here, but so be it -- my enthusiasm has run away with me. You are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

It's sloppy. It's saying that interns are a lab. And that's obviously not what the writer meant. (In fact, it's so obvious that you're the first person who didn't just glide right over it. Good call!)

Better:

- "As a research-intensive lab, we require interns . . . ."
- "Because the lab does research, interns are required . . . ."